# pd.DataFrame raise pandas error ('dataframe constructor not properly called ')

Tags: python, pandas

I am novice in Python language and I have to use it for building a Psychopy experiment.
I want to use Pandas for combining csv files created at the begining of each run of my experiment. But I have this Error message :

```
CompMgFile1 = pd.DataFrame(CompMgFile1,colimns=['Amorce','Target'])
raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I've read on similar topics that it could be my data file that does not correspond to the parameter. But I don't understand why beacause, my file is a csv file created at the begining of the experiment and I would have thought that it was a dataframe no ?

This is my code for the created files used to make the final condition file with pandas and the code for generating this final file.

```
import random 
import csv
```

I use the original_list.csv file to define my words instead of doing it explicitly. I open the file called ‘original_list.csv’ and read its contents into the variable ‘stimuli’

```
Stimuli=list(csv.reader(open('Original_list.csv',"rU"),delimiter=';'))
```

This original_list file lokks like that (for simplification : M is my Outgroup Primes, C my ingroup ones, N my negative targets and P my positive ones

```
M1  C1  N1  P1
M2  C2  N2  P2
M3  C3  N3  P3
M4  C4  N4  P4
M5  C5  N5  P5
M6  C6  N6  P6
M7  C7  N7  P7
M8  C8  N8  P8
M9  C9  N9  P9
M10 C10 N10 P10
```

Next I will create two ‘empty’ variables into which I will put the word lists

```
AmorceMg=[]
AmorceCau=[]
TargetN=[]
TargetP=[]
```

Next I will loop through the ‘stimuli’ object and place the appropriate words in their respective objects

```
for i in range(len(Stimuli)):
    AmorceMg.append(Stimuli[i][0])
    AmorceCau.append(Stimuli[i][1])
    TargetN.append(Stimuli [i][2])
    TargetP.append(Stimuli [i][3])
```

Now I take out the header line

```
AmorceMg=AmorceMg[1:]
AmorceCau=AmorceCau[1:]
TargetN=TargetN[1:]
TargetP=TargetP[1:]
```

Then I randomize them. This will create my 4 randomized word lists for the two blocks of trials

```
AmorceMgRand1=random.sample(AmorceMg,len(AmorceMg)) 
AmorceCauRand1=random.sample(AmorceCau,len(AmorceCau)) 
TargetNRand1=random.sample(TargetN,len(TargetN)) 
TargetPRand1=random.sample(TargetP,len(TargetP))

AmorceMgRand2=random.sample(AmorceMg,len(AmorceMg)) 
AmorceCauRand2=random.sample(AmorceCau,len(AmorceCau)) 
TargetNRand2=random.sample(TargetN,len(TargetN)) 
TargetPRand2=random.sample(TargetP,len(TargetP))
```

I define the ‘subjectID’ and ‘sessionID’ variables for naming the order files

```
subjectID=expInfo['participant']
sessionID=expInfo['session']
```

Now I create 4 file names based on compatibility for the first and second block

```
CompMgFile1=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_CompMg1.csv'
IncMgFile1=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_IncMg1.csv'
CompCauFile1=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_CompCau1.csv'
IncCauFile1=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_IncCau1.csv'

with open(CompMgFile1,'wb') as w: 
  writer=csv.writer(w) 
  writer.writerow(['Amorce','Target']) 
  for i in range(len(AmorceMgRand1)): 
    writer.writerow([AmorceMgRand1[i],TargetNRand1[i]]) 

with open(IncMgFile1,'wb') as w: 
  writer=csv.writer(w) 
  writer.writerow(['Amorce','Target']) 
  for i in range(len(AmorceMgRand1)): 
    writer.writerow([AmorceMgRand1[i],TargetPRand1[i]]) 

with open(CompCauFile1,'wb') as w: 
  writer=csv.writer(w) 
  writer.writerow(['Amorce','Target']) 
  for i in range(len(AmorceCauRand1)): 
    writer.writerow([AmorceCauRand1[i],TargetPRand1[i]]) 

with open(IncCauFile1,'wb') as w: 
  writer=csv.writer(w) 
  writer.writerow(['Amorce','Target']) 
  for i in range(len(AmorceCauRand1)): 
    writer.writerow([AmorceCauRand1[i],TargetNRand1[i]])

CompMgFile2=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_CompMg2.csv'
IncMgFile2=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_IncMg2.csv'
CompCauFile2=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_CompCau2.csv'
IncCauFile2=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_IncCau2.csv'

with open(CompMgFile2,'wb') as w: 
  writer=csv.writer(w) 
  writer.writerow(['Amorce','Target']) 
  for i in range(len(AmorceMgRand2)): 
    writer.writerow([AmorceMgRand2[i],TargetNRand2[i]]) 

with open(IncMgFile2,'wb') as w: 
  writer=csv.writer(w) 
  writer.writerow(['Amorce','Target']) 
  for i in range(len(AmorceMgRand2)): 
    writer.writerow([AmorceMgRand2[i],TargetPRand2[i]]) 

with open(CompCauFile2,'wb') as w: 
  writer=csv.writer(w) 
  writer.writerow(['Amorce','Target']) 
  for i in range(len(AmorceCauRand2)): 
    writer.writerow([AmorceCauRand2[i],TargetPRand2[i]]) 

with open(IncCauFile2,'wb') as w: 
  writer=csv.writer(w) 
  writer.writerow(['Amorce','Target']) 
  for i in range(len(AmorceCauRand2)): 
    writer.writerow([AmorceCauRand2[i],TargetNRand2[i]])
```

Now I create two file names based on precedent variables for each blocks

```
Block1=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_order1.csv'
Block2=subjectID + '_' + sessionID + '_order2.csv'
```

Now I merge all files for each blocks

```
import pandas as pd

CompMgFile1 = pd.DataFrame(CompMgFile1,columns=['Amorce', 'Target'])
IncMgFile1 = pd.DataFrame(IncMgFile1,columns=['Amorce', 'Target'])
CompCauFile1 = pd.DataFrame(CompCauFile1,columns=['Amorce', 'Target'])
IncCauFile1 = pd.DataFrame(IncCauFile1,columns=['Amorce', 'Target'])
CompMgFile2 = pd.DataFrame(CompMgFile2,columns=['Amorce', 'Target'])
IncMgFile2 = pd.DataFrame(IncMgFile2,columns=['Amorce', 'Target'])
CompCauFile2 = pd.DataFrame(CompCauFile2,columns=['Amorce', 'Target'])
IncCauFile2 = pd.DataFrame(IncCauFile2,columns=['Amorce', 'Target'])

merged = pd.concat([CompMgFile1, IncMgFile1, CompCauFile1,IncCauFile1])
merged.to_csv(Block1, index=None)

merged = pd.concat([CompMgFile2, IncMgFile2, CompCauFile2,IncCauFile2])
merged.to_csv(Block2, index=None)
```

Is anybody have an idea of the problem ?
Thank you very munch in advance for any help !

Ivane

Comment: Does any part of this program work? Try starting with one small piece of it. I'd think reading the first csv would be good. first_df = pd.read_csv(file)

Comment: [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) does not receive a csv file as input. Use the i/o method: [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Yes the creation of the first csv files works (CompMgFile1, CompMgFile2, IncMgFile1, IncMgFile2, CompCauFile1, CompCauFile2, IncCauFile1, IncCauFile2). This generate csv file which I think comma is the separator. The problem seems to be only when I use pandas.

Comment: It seems to work with pandas.read_csv !! Thank you very much to you two for your quick answers !!